# Is it possible to do calculations with numbers present in the text, purely in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I've created a plan in Word for a workshop I want to run.

The plan essentially looks like

```
Welcome - 5 minutes  
   Introduce myself, get to know team

Topic 1 - 30 minutes
   Cover this and that

Break - 15 minutes

Topic 2 - 30 minutes
    Cover other things
```

Now I want to show a total duration of the program.
I could calculate this manually, but as the duration of the different activities will change often (as I structure this and change my mind about what to add and what not to). As such, manually calculating each time can become tedious.

How can I automatically calculate the program duration based on the numbers I write in the text?

I understand that Word might not be the ideal tool for this, but my question isn't about an alternative software recommendation, it is specifically about Word.

Comment: Would you accept a method that uses Word and Excel via mailmerge? Or has this to be pure Word? If the latter, would VBA be acceptable? Or is that not pure enough?

Comment: Anything is accepted. It may be, I'm just using the wrong tool for the job

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this in Word by using Bookmarks and a Formula Field.

## Bookmarks

First you need to create a bookmark for every number that you want to sum.
I will show how to do this for one of the headers from your example text.
You will need to repeat this for every number that you would like to include in the calculation.

### Create a bookmark

1. Select the number in the section header:
   [image: Select number in text]
2. Go to `Insert -> Bookmark` and give the bookmark a meaningful name:
   [image: Insert Bookmark with a name]

### Create a formula field

This field will sum the numbers referenced by the bookmarks created earlier.

1. Go to `Insert -> Quick Parts -> Field`
2. Select the `= (Formula)` field and press the <kbd>Formula...</kbd> button
   [image: Insert formula field]
3. In the Formula window you can now type a formula after the `=` sign. For convenience you can pick the bookmarks from the `Paste bookmark` drop-down, or you can type the formula directly. In this example I created 4 bookmarks (one for each section header), so my formula looks like this:
   [image: Field formula calculating the total running time]
4. Click <kbd>OK</kbd> in the Formula window. Now the field is calculated:
   [image: Calculated total running time]

### Refresh the calculation

If you changed the value of any of your bookmarks, you need to right click the calculated field and update it:
[image: Update field]