# MS Word Field to Calculate Total Number of Credits in Exam

Tags: microsoft-word, field-codes

I am drafting an exam and I know how to create my own counter for the separate questions. I did this with Strg + F9 and `{seq questionno}`. I have also added text boxes to the lines with the number of credits that can be achieved in a particular question. This is what I have so far:

[image: draft exam questions with automatic question numbering in MS Word]

My question is: How can I automatically calculate the total number of credits?

---

What I was hoping to do was to turn the numbers in the text boxes into fields and then calculate the sum of all the values of that particular field.

I did find the solution using bookmarks [as described here](https://superuser.com/questions/1455263/is-it-possible-to-do-calculations-with-numbers-present-in-the-text-purely-in-wo/1455281#1455281). But this solution is intended for the sum of specific fields (i.e. bookmarks). The sum will have to be a manual addition of all the bookmarks (as can be seen in their figure):

[image: ms word sum of bookmarks]

This fails for example if I were to copy-paste my question 2 to create a question 3. Once I do an update with `F9` the number of the new question will be correct, but in the process Word will lose track of the bookmarks and the total sum will be wrong. Word sees this as the result:

[image: MS Word fails to compute the total number of credits]

I feel this has a simple solution, but I just do not know enough of the MS Word "field programming language" to do it myself.

---

Edit: I am aware that there are solutions using tables. I would prefer a solution without tables as there are various problems related to tables and I do not want to give up margin space for the credits.

Comment: Do I get you right that what you're asking for is automated new bookmarks when you copy-paste, plus an automatic summing of all those bookmarks ?

Comment: Also, are you aware that you will always have to refresh the calculation manually, after every edit (as is clearly stated in the answer you have linked) ? So there will never be an "automatic calculation".

Answer (score 2):

If you formulate this as a table, with the credits in a separate column,
you could use the formula of `=SUM(ABOVE)`.
This will transfer correctly on copy-paste of the entire table.

See the Microsoft article
[Sum a column or row of numbers in a table](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sum-a-column-or-row-of-numbers-in-a-table-110097a9-76c9-449d-a092-82df0ff548d0)
on how to create a SUM fields for a column:

[image]
[image]

You can copy-paste the entire table, and each copy will sum up only its
own columns, separately from the original.

Note that to recalculate the SUM formula after changing values
in the columns, you need to select the table and press <kbd>F9</kbd>.
You may also select the entire document with
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and then press <kbd>F9</kbd> to
recalculate the sums in all the tables of the document.

More information and methods can be found in the article
[3 Quick Ways to Sum Numbers in Your Word Table](https://www.datanumen.com/blogs/3-quick-ways-sum-numbers-word-table/).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out tables. I really don't want to use tables for my document and am looking for a solution without tables.

Comment: @fborchers: The tables don't have to be visible - you can create them without visible borders.